# resetOthermedia instead of pauseOther

Tags: mediaelement.js

Is there a solution to have this command instead of pauseOthermedia?
I have multiple mp3 player on one page and I would have the possibilities that when I play a player the player that I leave reset to 0 from the begining
best regards
dup